Amplification argument for hyperlinear groups
Let us define a group $G$ to be a hyperlinear group if it satisfies the conclusion of Theorem 3.6. in these notes by Vladimir Pestov. It is well-known that one can use the so-called amplification argument to replace $1/4$ by $ \sqrt{ 2}- \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon >0$ in this definition.
A similar argument for sofic approximations is due to Elek and Szabó. I am looking for a reference for the paper where this argument for hyperlinear groups was given for the first time. Just to be clear: I am familiar with the argument itself, and I am only looking for the reference. Any suggestion in locating the reference will be much appreciated.
